# Browser create <a> tags in the DOM but it's doesn't exist in my HTML index file

Tags: html

for some weird reason my browser keep creating  tag's that don't exist in my main html file , this block my ability to select element in javascript any know why is this happening ??

[image]

Comment: Check your browser extensions.

Comment: disabled them all still not working..

Comment: Try the html file in another PC

Comment: Then check the javascript

Comment: fixed it. it worked even though the tags still appear but for some reason they are been ignored now.. this really weird